# Convert a List<string> to DataRow in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable, datarow

I have a list of strings and am in need of converting it to a Datarow.
I tried

```
toReturn.Add("UserID");
toReturn.Add("UserName");
DataRow row = null;
row.ItemArray=toreturn.ToArray();
```

This is throwing me an exception

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

So i tried with

```
DataRow Row=new DataRow();
```

That is also not allowed.Can somebody help me in this.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using a `DataRow`.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 8):

`DataRow`s can only exist with a `DataTable`.

Create a `DataTable` with appropriate columns, then call `table.Rows.Add(list.ToArray())`.

However, you probably shouldn't be using `DataRow` in the first place.

Comment: I need to use this conversion in a method which returns a DataRow.So yo mean i need to create a table and rerturn the row ?

Comment: @Newto.net: You shouldn't have a method that returns a `DataRow`.  DataRows are a very bad way to transfer information.

Answer (score 3):

You can create `DataRow` object inside `DataTable` like SLaks pointed out.
Whatever the reason for  it...

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Test");

foreach(string x in array)
{
    DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();   
    dataRow["Test"] = x;   
    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);               
}
```

Now you can do whatever you want with your `DataTable` object...

Answer (score 2):

Try this, its working for me!!!

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Data;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace testApp

{

 class Program

 {

    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        List<string> toReturn = new List<string>();

        toReturn.Add("UserID");
        toReturn.Add("UserName");

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserID"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserName"));

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row.ItemArray = toReturn.ToArray();
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I used `row.ItemArray` on a larger table with various column types and found it much more efficient than setting each column in the DataRow individually.

Answer (score 0):

You might be required [`NewRow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create new `DataRow`:

```
DataRow row = _dataTable.NewRow();
```

Check `_dataTable` in your code.

Comment: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table. am getting someothr exception for this

Comment: @Newto.net If this the case then you must add some code and show what exactly you are trying do?

Answer (score 0):

```
string [] array=new string[length]{1,2,3,...}

DataTable dt=new DataTable();

DataRow toInsert = dt.NewRow();

toInsert.ItemArray = array;

dt.Rows.InsertAt(toInsert, desiredrownumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `List<string[]>` has the first row of the list as header, you can do something like this:

```
var header = records.Select(it => it).First().ToList();
var values = records.Select(it => it).Skip(1).ToList();
foreach (var item in header)
    dataTable.Columns.Add(item, typeof(string));

foreach (object[] value in values) 
    dataTable.Rows.Add(value);

return dataTable;
```